# Adding another variable in image src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, image, src

```
<img src="blank.png" id="image" alt="just nothing">

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('image').src = '"'+ img +'"';
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/696014803844927488/8aLamHjS.jpg";
</script>
```

It's not working. I'm confused.

Comment: You're accessing the variable `img` before you declare it.

Comment: ~That's not actually true, `img` would be hoisted to the top of the script. So it exists, but the src isn't correct.~

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? And `document.getElementById('image').src = '"'+ img +'"';` should be `document.getElementById('image').src = img.src;`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t6t4cnjg/

Comment: The second two lines are unnecessary, you can just write `document.getElementById('image').src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/696014803844927488/8aLamHjS.jpg";`

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the variable `image` before you declare it, your code should be like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/696014803844927488/8aLamHjS.jpg";

document.getElementById('image').src = img.src;
```

Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfzx0kxn/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```js
var img = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
document.getElementById('image').src = img ;
```

```html
<img src="blank.png" id="image" alt="just nothing">
```

You can directly apply the src

```js
 document.getElementById('image').src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
```

```html
<img src="blank.png" id="image" alt="just nothing">
```